# How to interact javascript variable in ERB file??

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var school_name = $('input#search_school_name_like').val();
  });
</script>
```

In my erb file, I need to check,

```
If school_name is not nil?

    <%= link_to "link" students_path(:range => 'A-B',:school_name => school_name) %>
    else
    <%= link_to "link" students_path(:range => 'A-B) %>
```

How to communicate between javascript and erb file? Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code is executed in user's browser, and `ERB` file is being processed on server. That means you cannot use Javascript variables in Ruby code. So the code like `link_to "link" students_path(:range => 'A-B',:school_name => school_name)` won't work. You have to create a path manually in Javascript:

```
var path = "/students?range=A-B&school_name=" + school_name;
```